# A lemma about Lyapunov stability theorem

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In order to talk about Lyapunov stability theorem, we need this lemma:
Assume $u(t)$ is a function:
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u(t)\in C[a,b] \\
u(t) \in C^2(a,b) \\
u(a) = u(b) = 0 \\
u(t) > 0,  \forall t \in (a,b)
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
Prove $\large\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\left | u''(t)) \right |}{u(t))} dt > \frac{4}{b-a}$.